# Uncaught TypeError: $(…).modal is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

So, this code is supposed to show JQuery table, and in the third column, every row is clickable and when clicked it shows a Modal.

When i start the code, the table shows, and when i clicked the third row, the alert test works, but the modal didnt show, and in the console it printed an [error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z3Ou5.png):

```
UnCaught TypeError: topics.jsx 
$(...).modal is not a function
```

So clearly the show modal function in the .click(function()) does not work, some similar questions from StackOverflow is saying that `bootstrap.min.js` and `jquery.min.js` is not referenced,  but i'm not sure if that is the case because im using those libraries in this page no problem.

How do i fix this?

**topics.jsx**:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import ReactDOMServer from 'react-dom/server';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import Navbar, { MENU as MAIN_MENU } from '../../components/Navbar';
import TopicFilter from '../../components/TopicFilter';
import PeriodTag from '../../components/PeriodTag';
import LecturerInfo from '../../components/LecturerInfo';
import Layout from '../../components/layouts';
import { Nav, NavItem, NavLink, Collapse, Modal, ModalBody, ModalHeader, Button, Form, FormGroup, FormInput, Alert } from "shards-react";



var $ = require('jquery');
var dt = require('datatables.net')();

class TopicTable extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);


        $(document).ready(() => {
            $('#topic-table').DataTable({
                data: this.props.topics || [],
                columns: [
                    { data: 'id', visible: false }, //id
                    { data: 'name' }, //name
                    { data: 'quota' }, //quota
                    { data: 'deskripsi'}, //DESKRIPSI
                    { data: 'kk', visible: false }, //kk
                    { data: 'peminatan', render: 'abbrev' }, //peminatan
                    { data: 'period', render: 'semester' }, //period
                    { //lecturer
                        data: 'lecturer',
                        /*render: function(data, type, row, meta) {
                            if (type=='display') {
                                const lecturerInfo = (
                                    <LecturerInfo
                                        nik={data.nik}
                                        name={data.name}
                                        lecturerCode={data.lecturerCode}
                                    />
                                );
                                return ReactDOMServer.renderToString(lecturerInfo)
                            }
                        }*/
                        render: 'name'
                    },
                    { data: 'isDeleted', visible: false } //isDeleted

                ]

                
            })
            $('#topic-table').find('td:nth-child(3)').click(function() {
                alert($(this).html());

                $('#myModal').modal('show'); //FUNCTION TO SHOW MODAL
                
              });


        })
    }

   

    componentDidUpdate() {
        $(function () {
            $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover()
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                //MODAL
                    <div class="modal" id="myModal">
                        <div class="modal-dialog">
                            <div class="modal-content">

                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Heading</h4>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    </div>

                    <div class="modal-body">
                        Modal body..
                    </div>

                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            //TABLE
            <table id="topic-table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th bgcolor="#E8E8E8">Id</th>
                        <th bgcolor="#E8E8E8">Topik</th>
                        <th bgcolor="#E8E8E8">Quota</th>
                        <th bgcolor="#E8E8E8">Deskripsi</th>
                        <th bgcolor="#E8E8E8">KK</th>
                        <th bgcolor="#E8E8E8">Peminatan</th>
                        <th bgcolor="#E8E8E8">Semester</th>
                        <th bgcolor="#E8E8E8">Dosen</th>
                        <th bgcolor="#E8E8E8">sudah dihapus</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
  
            </table>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

TopicTable.propTypes = {
    topics: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.object)
}

function Page() {
    const { currentPeriod, topics, peminatanList } = window.SAILS_LOCALS;
    return (
        <div className="page main-content-container px-4 pb-4 container-fluid">
            {/* <Navbar activeMenu={MAIN_MENU.TOPICS} /> */}
            <div className="container">
                <h2 class="display-4">Daftar Topik <PeriodTag period={currentPeriod} /></h2>
                <div>
                    <TopicFilter peminatanList={peminatanList} />
                    <TopicTable topics={topics} />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

ReactDOM.render(<Layout><Page /></Layout>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: Try to add the Jquery in your index.html file instead of require('jquery');

Answer (score 0):

jQuery doesn't have a `modal` method.

There are various plugins which add such a method, including [bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/).

To use a plugin, you need to register it with jQuery.

In traditional web programming, this is done by:

- Adding a `<script>` element which loads jQuery and creates `jQuery` and `$` as globals.
- Adding a `<script>` element which loads the plugin, which accesses one of those global variables and modifies the object assigned to it.

In your code, you are assigning a value to `$` with `require`. It is *locally* scoped to the JS module. If you had loaded the Bootstrap JS which would have added the plugin with a `<script>` in the page then it would have either thrown an error, or associated the plugin with a *different* copy of the jQuery object.

Since you are working with React, use [React Bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/modal/) which provides things like the Bootstrap Modal as React components.